# Performance issues with small dedicated plesk centos5 server

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, fastcgi

I am getting some fairly sever performance issues with my plesk 11 dedicated box, it has 8 gigs of ram, static pages load very fast, a firstbyte time of less then 0.5 seconds, however dynamic php files, including just a php info can take between 1 (straight after a httpd restart) and 10 seconds for the firstbyte.

Ive been measuring the performance with WebPagetest.org

The server runs 1 site, with 4000 visitors a month, it should not be under any real load.

PHP runs as CGI

Heres the httpd configuration for prefork

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  1000
</IfModule>
```

Also the log files fill with this

```
[Tue Apr 09 05:58:23 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 4435 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Apr 09 05:58:55 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 4466 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Apr 09 05:59:11 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 4475 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

Any suggestions are more then welcome, i cannot figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your PHP scripts just take much too long. Check them, see if/where they could be doing too much computation.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments, its just a Joomla install, and was running far faster on lower spec VPS then it is on this dedicated box, i dont think it can suddenly be much more CPU intensive.

Comment: Abit late but.. did you ever find a solution for this problem?